# Three.js - How do I change the edge colors of my SphereGeometry object?

Tags: javascript, web, three.js, 3d

This is the basic example from the Threejs documentation

```
function initSphere(){
       const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 150, 14, 14 );
       const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xFF0000, vertexColors: 0xFFFFFF} );
       const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
       scene.add( sphere );
}
```

It creates a red sphere which is what I wanted, but I can't really see the sphere and it's edges because it just looks like a red circle. I was thinking that changing the edges to a white color would help make the effect I want, but I can't seem to know how to ask this question to solve it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: As an option, you can add a light source (THREE.DirectionalLIght, for example) and use a material that can be affected by light (THREE.Mesh.LambertMaterial({color: "red"}), for example).

Comment: [MeshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial) is always flat. Like prisoner849 mentioned above, a light and Lambert material or [Phong](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial) if you want specular highlights would make your sphere look better.

Answer (score 0):

First, your shape is "just a red circle" because you are using `MeshBasicMaterial`. This material is simply a color and does not include any kind of shading or highlights--it doesn't even need a light source! Every bit of the shape will be rendered as `0xff0000`.

If you want shading/highlights, You will need to use a more complex material like `MeshPhongMaterial`, `MeshLambertMaterial`, or `MeshStandardMaterial`. Because these are shaded, you *will* need to include a light in your scene.

Secondly, the `vertexColors` property does not change the color of the "edges." Instead, it is [a Boolean that indicates whether vertex colors are used to color the Mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.vertexColors).

If you want to show edges, you could try using [`EdgesGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/EdgesGeometry) to define a secondary shape.